# alert message if default value on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert "enter values for all fields" on a form submission if a text field equals its default value. it doesn't seem to be working properly. Any help would be great

```
$("#info").submit(function() {
    if ($(".TextField").val() == ('defaultValue')) {
        alert("enter value for all fields")
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("ok");
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: You should add your HTML code too

Comment: Also, use triple equals for comparisons in if-statements whenever possible.

Comment: If default value is a variable then remove '  ' from it

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your issue:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info').click(function(e) {                        
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "defaultValue") {
               alert("Enter value for all fields");
               return false;
            }
            else {
                alert("Ok");
            } 
        });
    });
});
```